# How to add dynamic query parameters in Retrofit2 OkHttpClient Interceptor?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2 to connect to REST based API. Problem is it requires lat/lng position, but only for about 50% of endpoints. I am wondering how should I dynamically add query parameter into OkHttpClient, based on some boolean. My code for now:

```
public static APIEndpointInterface getHttpClient(Boolean addLatLng){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                        LatLng location = App.getLocationRepository().getCurrentLocation();
                        String lat = String.valueOf(location.latitude);
                        String lng = String.valueOf(location.longitude);

                        Request request = chain.request();
                        HttpUrl url = request.url().newBuilder()
                                .addQueryParameter("version", API_VERSION)
                                .addQueryParameter("app_version_code", String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE))
                                //ADD ONLY IF BOOLEAN PASSED TO METHOD IS TRUE
                                .addQueryParameter("lat", lat)
                                .addQueryParameter("lng", lng)
                                .port(PORT_HTTPS)
                                .build();
                        ......
```

Is there other option than adding lat/lng to every second interface method?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found solution myself. If it helps anyone:

```
Request request = chain.request();
HttpUrl.Builder builder = request.url().newBuilder();
builder.addQueryParameter("version", API_VERSION);
builder.addQueryParameter("app_version_code",String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE));
if (location) {
    builder.addQueryParameter("lat", lat);
    builder.addQueryParameter("lng", lng);
}
HttpUrl url = builder.build();
request = request.newBuilder()
         .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
         .url(url)
         .build();
```